# Flutter doctor fails to get dart-sdk

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

Flutter doctor fails to get `dart-sdk`

here is an image for command prompt:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using Powershell instead of command prompt?

Comment: yea and it gave me that error here (http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/19ce/u08dw1nvahqea2pzg.jpg)

Comment: Try running it as an administrator at some other location instead of C:\windows...